# Rails4 how to call Javascripts , stylesheets and images from other folders not from (vendor, lib , app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have one problem I have to call assets (Javascripts , stylesheets and images) from other folders apart from the application default assets folder, I don't have any idea how to call it.

I have tried append_view_path function but did not solve my problem,  here is the link 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-location-3D

Can anyone suggest the best way to load assets.

Comment: Best way to load assets? In the appropriate folders. Can you give a more concrete example of where you are trying to load them from?

Comment: I have developed a Rails application and in that there are two sections one is Admin and other is frontend section. So now all the assets for the admin are loading from the main (app, lib , vendor , public) and for the frontend I have created a folder with symlink and loading all request from page_render_controller but in this case my assets are not loading because it is not part of the main app thats why I need to load all the js, css and images for the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will placed you js and css file in public folder in the assets folder then require in the application.js and application.css like :

**application.js**

```
  //= require app
```

application.css

```
 *= require dist/css/skins/skin-blue.min.css
```